# How would I parallize a nested for loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Hi I would like some help on dividing up this problem into smaller tasks that can be processed at the same time (parallel)

```
for (numbers){  

for(each number){   
  128  **This is ok**  
}  
for(each n, n){   
   128 x 128  **This is ok**  
}   
  for(each n, n, n){   
   128 x 128 x 128  **Needs to be parallized from here**  
}   
for(each n, n, n, n){  
   128 x 128 x 128 x 128  
}        
}
```

I was thinking of trying to implement forkjoin or mapReduce but I'm a complete newbie and I don't know how to get started on this.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted actual code. Have you read the [fok/join tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)?

Comment: actually, read the whole concurrency tutorial, if it has any news for you... For splitting, you will not get good speedups if your jobs take less time than 1ms. Also make sure they are really independent.